# nohup command getting permission issues

Tags: unix, filesystems, permission-denied, nohup

I am trying to run a filewatcher.sh script in background. It further invokes a java code through a jar file.

Whenever I run the command("nohup sh filewatcher.sh") through terminal, everything is ok. I have to hit enter two times so the output file is appended to nohup.out. But whenever I try to run the equivalent command("nohup filewatcher.sh >> nohup.out < /dev/null &") from a shell script **automate.sh**, I get following permission error.

[error-log. Click to see snippet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCKSw.png)

Could this an issue of permission for the **automate.sh**? 
I have crossed check to see this script is having same permissions and ownership as the user when I log in and enter the nohup command from command line.
I also checked the ownership of the folders where the files are getting moved but everything is having same permissions and ownership.

Comment: I think the java code is using relative paths and when it is executed via a shell script, the folder where the script resides, becomes the base folder and java code searches for a file there and fails.

Comment: @NikhilSahu I shortened the description a bit. When I run from command line, I do go specific path to run that command but when I run from script, I give absolute path so that it rules out the possibility of being wrong. Example in script I wrote : "nohup /path/to/filewatcher/filewatcher.sh >> /path/to/filewatcher/nohup.out < /dev/null &"